# How to create a image slide show with scroll function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Want to create a slideshow of different images for a project with HTML, JS, and CSS. I want to create a scroll function that will move the image slides from left to right based on the movement of the mouse scroll.

If this sounds confusing this link shows exactly what I'm trying to do but due to my lack of experience, I have no idea how to accomplish this. Any ideas would help.

link: https://robbiecrenshaw.com/ about the halfway mark

thank you

(I'm a beginner in programming)

Answer (score 1):

The animations used on this site are called scroll-based animations, where the animation progress is controlled directly by the scroll position.

They are implemented by listening to the scroll event that is fired when a user scrolls and updating the styles of certain elements dynamically based on the scroll position.

You can create scroll animations from scratch using JavaScript or implement them using a library like GSAP ScrollTrigger (which is what this specific site uses).

I created a demo similar to the effect you're looking for here: https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/yLVEZPa

This example uses ScrollMagic to track the scroll position and update the `transform` property of an element to make the squares move left as you scroll down the page.